# Selecting mysql data across 3 tables where belongs and does not belong?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have the following tables:

Course

```
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| c_id        | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| c_name      | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Articles

```
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| a_id        | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| a_name      | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Course_Articles

```
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| ca_id       | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| a_id        | bigint(20)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| c_id        | bigint(20)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| t_id        | bigint(20)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| sort_order  | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Term (or semester)

```
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| t_id        | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| t_name      | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| c_id        | bigint(20)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| sort_order  | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I need to present the data from these tables as follows:

**Course Name:** Modern Gas Extraction

**Articles:**

- Intro
- Overview of gas extraction techniques
- **Term 1:** Conventional Techniques

  - Coal Mine Methane
  - Another conventional technique
- Another article not in a term
- Another one
- **Term 2:** Unconventional Techniques

  - Underground Coal Gasification
  - Coal Bed Methane
  - Hydraulic Fracturing
- Conclusions

I know this data would benefit from perhaps nesting/tree. But it is what I have to work with. As you can see Articles can belong to a Term or be free standing.

I am a bit stumped as to how to efficiently query the above to output as per the example.

```
<?php
// UPDATED with UNION as suggested
try {
$stmt = $dbh->prepare(
    "SELECT ca . * , a.a_name, t.t_name
FROM Course_Article AS ca 
LEFT JOIN Article AS a ON a.a_id = ca.ca_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN Term AS t ON t.t_id = ca.t_id
WHERE ca.c_id = '2'
UNION SELECT te.t_name, te.t_id, te.c_id
FROM Term AS te
WHERE te.t_id = '2'");

$last_term_id = -1;

$stmt->execute();
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  if ($last_term_id != $row['t_id']) {
    echo "<b>" . $row['t_name'] . "</b><br />";
    $last_term_id = $row['t_id'];
  }
  echo $row['a_name'] . "<br />";
  }
 } catch(PDOException $e) {
  echo 'Error : '. $e->getMessage();
  exit();
  }
?>
```

Thank you

Comment: Don't mix join styles. In fact, you won't go far wrong if you never use comma joins at all.

Comment: 'efficiently query' - well put :) your sql query has quite basic level errors, i.e. maybe you should try studying a bit more about the sql basics before asking for assistance (=solutions) from others.

Comment: I had a brain fart. I guess you don't get those. ;)

Comment: ah, I do too, don't worry. The query looks much better now. So is the question now about whether the query could be optimized or how to get the example printout from the sql result?

Comment: Thx ejuhjav I still need to display the terms when they are empty of articles. I expect I can work the print out logic. It's the JOINS wot got me.

Comment: To get the empty terms in the same query you need to do some more modifications to your query - simple solution would be to create second query to get the related empty terms.

Comment: maybe you need to use union query to get all the articles in and out of terms in a single query. But no more time today - but if no one else picks this up in between, I can try to create some crude example of how to do it with union

Answer (score 0):

So here is one idea how to do it with union: first part gets all the terms (also the empty ones) and articles under them, and second part gets all the additional articles that belong to the course but not to any term. Hopefully I didn't include too many logic/typo mistakes here.

```
select t.t_name, ca.*, a.a_name
from Term t
left outer join Course_Article ca ON ca.t_id = t.t_id
left outer join Article a ON a.a_id = ca.a_id
where t.c_id = '2'

UNION

select null as t_name, ca.*, a.a_name
from Course_Articles ca
left outer join Article a ON a.a_id = ca.a_id
where ca.c_id = '2' and ca.t_id is null
```

Additionally, if you would need to order the result a bit (dunno if the sorting order is generic between the course article and term), you can extend this a bit (add whatever columns you need to the final result into the main select):

```
select t_name, a_name, sort_column
FROM
(
    select t.t_name, ca.*, a.a_name, t.sort_order as sort_column
    from Term t
    left outer join Course_Article ca ON ca.t_id = t.t_id
    left outer join Article a ON a.a_id = ca.a_id
    where t.c_id = '2'

    UNION

    select null as t_name, ca.*, a.a_name, ca.sort_order as sort_column
    from Course_Articles ca
    left outer join Article a ON a.a_id = ca.a_id
    where ca.c_id = '2' and ca.t_id is null
) dt
order by sort_column ASC
```

Comment: Thx ejuhjav, 1st one seems to almost do it, though for some reason a term that has 2 articles is returned 4 times (2 x with the incorrect c_id and 2 x with the correct c_id and related article). Sorting is important so I'll try that. This is closest yet though!

Comment: I updated the answer a bit (removed one unnecessary join from second part of the union): did you check already which part of the union results in too many/incorrect rows?

Comment: I get an error now as the removal of the left outer join loses us the term name.

Comment: ah, sorry, didn't mention the related modification: the t_name selection was modified also accordingly when I removed the table join, i.e. 'select null as t_name...' instead of the old 'select t.t_name...' (that was probably the cause of the current error?)

Comment: That did fix the error, but left us without the independent articles and still with the duplicated terms. I think I may have to insist on a structural change as I am certain this could be done much more cleanly and efficiently. Really appreciate the input ejuhjav.